# Where do I ask a question about Intellectual Property and fair use

Tags: support, stack-exchange, scope

I wanted to ask a question regarding fair use of IP(How much text,data can be quoted from a copyrighted website/textbook under fairuse?). The topic is not related to programming. Is there a place on SE where I can ask the question?

Comment: If interested in IP+IT you might like to contribute to http://itlaw.wikia.com/wiki/The_IT_Law_Wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found site [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) (which is part of stackexchange) with questions related to IP and fair use :

- http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/intellectual-property
- http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/tagged/copyright

Comment: Websites don't exist

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no SE site for which that question is on-topic. You may wish to support the [IP Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3346/intellectual-property-law) or any of the more general legal proposals on Area 51.

Comment: followed the proposal.

Comment: `This proposal has been deleted.` now what to do?