# Questions about intellectual property, inventions

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I ask a question about Intellectual Property and fair use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83473/where-do-i-ask-a-question-about-intellectual-property-and-fair-use)

Is there any site on stackexchange to ask questions related with intellectual property law, inventions etc ?